# WebView remote site and reward videos

Tags: android, admob, android-webview, reward

I have a simple game developed in PHP. I have loaded the remote site in Android WebView. I want to find out that if user clicks on a FREE life button which is on my remote PHP site, I want to start a reward video on my Android app.

But how can I know whether the user clicked on the FREE life button in my WebView and start the video instantly in my android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Android mechanism that alows you to run Android function from javascript:

```
        <input class="button" type="button" value="FREE life" onclick="startRewardVideo('some parameters can be passed to Android from here')">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function startRewardVideo(paramFromJS) {
                    Android.startRewardVideoAndroidFunction(paramFromJS);
                }
            </script>
```

now you need class that knows what to do with your javascript:

```
public class MyJavaScriptInterface {

   @JavascriptInterface // this annotation is importatn
   public void startRewardVideoAndroidFunction(String paramFromJS) {

      //here you need to start showing reward movie 
      //because this function will be called after webView button click.
   }
}
```

last step is to connect webView with your javascript interface:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
```

and of course don't forget to enable javascript for your webView:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Hope it helps :) Ask if you have any questions on this.

Here you have full [tutorial](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2017/01/10/how-to-call-android-function-from-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I doubt is, as I am importing remote PHP website in my webview, will the function executed on my Android app?

Also the same will fail if someone uses the PHP site directly from browser. But I am not worrying about it.

Comment: JS executed on remote site is crucial so you need to add this. This solution won't work if you cant execute this JS on button click.